# proc sql/SAS: Create a case when a column is = this and row =that then col=1 row=2

Tags: sql, sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfnaT.png)

This is how my data looks like
[image]

and I want to print out a when

blue and red are the same, then print col=010 and row=200 and I want to to do that for 64 observations.

My try for ONE cell is:

```
proc sql;
create table ____matrix as
select *,
(case
when 'red'=' ' and 'blue'=' ' then col='0010' and row='0110'
when ....
uptil [64 times.}
else .
end)
from final
;quit
;
```

I also tried

```
proc sql;
create table ____matrix as
select *,
(case
when 'red'='blue' then col='0010' and row='0110'
when ....
uptil [64 times.}
else .
end)
from final
;quit
;
```

but it is not working. col and row btw is a character and the rest is numeric data

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make a lick of sense to me... try in English first.  Your data doesn't really make any sense.  What does this represent?  What do you actually want to do with it?  Red and Blue don't seem to be anything, and everything is a zero...  and why do col and row have the particular values they do?

Comment: Why is row 200? You need to explain the logic behind your table structure. Also, SQL is unlikely to be the right approach when you're looking to access data via the column/row structure. Perhaps you should look into SAS/IML which is closer to R/Python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is actually the target, the input data look strange. I can assume that you have numeric columns blue, red, green, etc. and you would like to fill columns col and row based on their values. Your sql code might look then this way:

```
proc sql;
create table ____matrix as
select *,
(case
when red=blue then '0010'
when red=green then '0020' 
/*uptil [64 times.}*/
else ''
end) as col,
(case
when red=blue then '0110'
when red=green then '0220' 
/*uptil [64 times.}*/
else ''
end) as row
from final
;
quit;
```

Using data step instead of proc sql; would help you to make the code easier.